# How to perform a query using a field that is a merge of 2 columns?

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark

I'm building up a series of distribution analysis using Java Spark library. This is the actual code I'm using to fetch the data from a JSON file and save the output.

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().json("local/foods.json");
        dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("cs_food");

List<GenericAnalyticsEntry> menu_distribution= spark
        .sql(" ****REQUESTED QUERY ****")
        .toJavaRDD()
        .map(row -> Triple.of( row.getString(0), BigDecimal.valueOf(row.getLong(1)), BigDecimal.valueOf(row.getLong(2))))
        .map(GenericAnalyticsEntry::of)
        .collect();

writeObjectAsJsonToHDFS(fs, "/local/output/menu_distribution_new.json", menu_distribution);
```

The query I'm looking for is based on this structure:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| FIRST_FOOD | SECOND_FOOD | DATE       | IS_SPECIAL |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| Pizza      | Spaghetti   | 11/02/2017 | TRUE       |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| Lasagna    | Pizza       | 12/02/2017 | TRUE       |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| Spaghetti  | Spaghetti   | 13/02/2017 | FALSE      |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| Pizza      | Spaghetti   | 14/02/2017 | TRUE       |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| Spaghetti  | Lasagna     | 15/02/2017 | FALSE      |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| Pork       | Mozzarella  | 16/02/2017 | FALSE      |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| Lasagna    | Mozzarella  | 17/02/2017 | FALSE      |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

How can I achieve this (written below) output from the code written above?

```
+------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| FOODS      | occurrences(First) | occurrences (Second) |
+------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| Pizza      | 2                  | 1                    |
+------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| Lasagna    | 2                  | 1                    |
+------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| Spaghetti  | 2                  | 3                    |
+------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| Mozzarella | 0                  | 2                    |
+------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| Pork       | 1                  | 0                    |
+------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

I've of course tried to figure out a solution by myself but had no luck with the my tries, I may be wrong, but I need something like this:

```
"SELECT (first_food + second_food) as menu, COUNT(first_food), COUNT(second_food) from cs_food GROUP BY menu"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example data, this looks like it will produce the output you want:

```
select
    foods,
    first_count,
    second_count
from
    (select first_food as food from menus
    union select second_food from menus) as f
    left join (
        select first_food, count(*) as first_count from menus
        group by first_food
        ) as ff on ff.first_food=f.food
    left join (
        select second_food, count(*) as second_count from menus
        group by second_food
        ) as sf on sf.second_food=f.food
 ;
```

Comment: This code gives me this result:
'Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'menus.`first_food`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(count(1) AS `first_count`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap 'menus.`first_food`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.'

Comment: My bad: I left out the `GROUP BY` clauses.  Fixed now.

Comment: EDIT: Needed to replace the first line of the select from "foods" to "food" and it's working... BUT the results of the not common fields are NULL instead of 0, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: in your select, try                                                                                     "select
    foods,                                                                            
   ISNULL(first_count, 0),                                                                           
   ISNULL(second_count, 0)"

Comment: Used this fix and it's working: 
 COALESCE(first_count,0)

Answer (score 0):

Simple combination of flatMap and groupBy should do the job like this (sorry, can't check if it 100% correct right now):

```
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
val df = Seq(("Pizza", "Pasta"), ("Pizza", "Soup")).toDF("first", "second")
df.flatMap({case Row(first: String, second: String) => Seq((first, 1, 0), (second, 0, 1))})
  .groupBy("_1")
```